# LaunchUri with launcher option always fails on Windows 10 mobile

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

To launch another specific app we can set the other app's package family name:

```
var options = new LauncherOptions();
options.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = packageFamilyName;

Uri uri = new Uri(protocol);
var succeeded = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options);
```

If the other app wasn't installed, Store download page opens. But this happens only on Windows 10 desktop, on the phone nothing happens, it just fails.

However if we remove `options` parameter it searches for any app on Store.

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

Is there anyway to have Desktop behavior on Mobile too? I mean open exactly a specific app not any app that registered for that protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcheroptions#Windows_System_LauncherOptions_PreferredApplicationPackageFamilyName) states this is for Desktop only at this point in time. Potentially the feature will make it to Mobile (and other Windows flavours) in the future.

Comment: Thanks Peter.. Is there a new flavor of any type in progress?